# Insert into a BigQuery table with a template suffix using the web-ui

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the Big Query Streaming API its possible to partition tables with a [template suffix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables):

`<targeted_table_name> + <templateSuffix>`
eg. `targettable_suffix`

How can this be done from the web ui in an insert statement?

For example:

```
insert into `project123.dataset123.targettable_suffix`
(`id`, `value`) values ('123', 'abc')
```

(Where a table exists called `targettable` but the suffix table has not been created.)

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` statement requires that the target table has been created in advance. Use a CREATE TABLE statement first to create it, then use INSERT. Note that the BigQuery team strongly recommends using [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) instead of multiple tables that share a prefix, however, and if you use a partitioned table, you only need to create it once.